# Strong epimorphic counit iff conservative right adjoint?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, 2-categories

On page 13 of Lack and Street's [*Combinatorial Categorical Equivalences*](http://maths.mq.edu.au/~street/CombCatEq.pdf), it is written (but not proven) that:

> A right adjoint is conservative if and only if the components of the counit are strong epimorphisms.

I have not read their paper, but stumbled upon it as I searched for necessary and sufficient condition for a right adjoint to be conservative. I have been unable to find a reference or proof of the stated result (though another paper of Street likewise mentions it).

I would like a proof of as general a statement as possible (e.g. something like in a strict $2$-category, given a right Kan lift with counit $\epsilon$ of a $1$-morphism $Y\xrightarrow{J} Z$ that is respected by $X\xrightarrow{F} Y$ and conservative on $2$-morphisms with domain $X\xrightarrow{F} Y$, then the right Kan lift is likewise conservative on all $2$-morphisms with that domain if and only if the $2$-moprhism $\epsilon F$ is a strong epi-$2$-morphism).

I will of course also accept proof for the simple case of right adjoints being conservative if and only if the counit is a strong epimorphism, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what kind of generalizations are you looking for, but the above statement is completely false even in case of ordinary categories (and you can easily find a counterexample).

It is true, however, under some additional assumptions (like, finite completeness).

Check the following question:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143070/two-pullback-diagram

and its answers. You may extract the proof from Lemma 2 and Lemma 3 from my note:

http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.2974

The correct versions of your statement are a kind of categorical folklore. I think that the statement was originally studied and proved (under various assumptions, including finite completeness) by John Isbell, though I do not recall any exact reference at the moment.

Comment: Would you mind writing up (or giving a reference to) the proof when (I presume) the domain category of the right adjoint is finitely complete?

Comment: I know I'm 4 years and a half late, but if anyone in the future is interested : the proof can be found in Kelly's "Basic concepts of enriched category theory" (available online, as part of the TAC reprints series), just before section 3.5 (page 44 of the TAC reprints version).