# If the counits of an adjunction are epimorpihsms then the right adjoint reflects monomorphisms?

Tags: category-theory

Given an adjunction $F \dashv G$, I need to show that if the counits $\varepsilon_Y: FG(Y) \rightarrow Y$ are epimorphisms then $G$ reflects monomorphisms. I am completely stuck on what properties of epis and monos I should use, so any pointer in the right direction would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the Yoneda Lemma, we have, for any locally small category $\mathcal C$, a bijection of sets
$$
\text{Nat}(\mathcal C(a,-),\mathcal C(b,-)) = \mathcal C(b,a)
$$
That means a natural transformation between the two representable functors is uniquely determined by an arrow $f:b\to a$. Indeed, if $f:b\to a$, then the natural transformation $f^*$ sends $g:a\to c$ to $gf:b\to c$. This implies that $f$ is epic if and only if each component of $f^*:\mathcal C(a,-)\Rightarrow\mathcal C(b,-)$ is an injection.
Given an adjunction $(F,G):\mathcal X\to\mathcal A$, we have a sequence of natural transformations
$$
\mathcal A(a,-)\Rightarrow\mathcal  X(Ga,G-)\Rightarrow\mathcal  A(FGa,-)
$$
The first sends an arrow $g:a\to b$ to the arrow $Gg$, and the second one sends that arrow to its adjunct $(Gg)^\sharp$. By the Yoneda Lemma, the composite transformation $\sigma$ is given by the arrow $\sigma_a(1_a)=(G1_a)^\sharp=1_{Ga}^\sharp=\varepsilon_a$, and it sends $g:a\to b$ to the arrow $g\epsilon_a$, thus $\sigma=\varepsilon_a^*$.
By the above remark, $\varepsilon_a^*$ is always injective iff this counit is an epimorphism. If all counits are epimorphisms, then every map $\mathcal A(a,b)\to \mathcal X(Ga,Gb)$ is injective, which means that $G$ is faithful.

Now you can just use the fact that faithful functors reflect monomorphisms (and epimorphisms).

On the other hand, if $G$ reflects epimorphisms, then each $ε_a$ must be an epimorphism. To see this, recall that for every adjunction $(F,g,\eta,ε)$, we have identities $Gε_a\circ\eta_{Ga}=1_{Ga}$ and $ε_{Fx}\circ F\eta_x=1_{Fx}$, so the image of every counit is a retraction, thus an epi.

Comment: That's a nice answer, thanks. I was wondering if there is something similar to the "remark" you made in the beginning that would make a similar argument work for the situation when the counits are extremal epic. It should follow that the right adjoint then reflects iso.

Comment: @user198182: I'm going through some problem sheets of a CT lecture I attended, and one of the problems is:
$$\text{(a) The following are equivalent: $\\$
i. $G$ is faithful, $\\$
ii. $G$ reflects epimorphisms, $\\$
iii. each $ε_A$ is an epimorphism. $\\$
(b) $G$ is full iff all $ε_A$ are sections. $\\$
(c) The following are equivalent: $\\$
i. $G$ is faithful and reflects isomorphisms, $\\$
ii. $G$ reflects extremal epimorphisms, $\\$
iii. each $ε_A$ is an extremal epimorphism.}$$
I still don't know how to prove (c). You could make that another question here (if it hasn't been asked before).

Comment: @user198182: I found this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915675/g-conservative-iff-counit-components-are-extremal-epi

Comment: Excellent. Thanks.