# Is this a conservative functor?

Tags: category-theory

I'd like to have some conditions under which the functor $C^I \stackrel{\lim}{\to} C $ is conservative.

If $C = \text{Set}$ and $I$ is discrete, I proved it is conservative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functor $\lim$ is right adjoint to the diagonal functor $\Delta:C\to C^{I}$. In general, a right adjoint functor between two finitely complete categories is conservative if and only if every components of the counit is an extremal epimorphism; so in this case we obtain that $\lim$ is conservative if and only if for all $F:I\to C$ and for all object $x$ of $I$, the natural map $\lambda_x:\lim_I F\to F(x)$ is an extremal epimorphism.

For your example of $C=\mathbf{Set}$ and $I$ discrete, it works because the product projections are split epimorphisms (assuming no set in the product is empty); but it doesn't hold for equalizers in general, since apart from trivial case they cannot be epic.

Comment: Great! Thanks, where did you read the lemma: "a right adjoint functor between two finitely complete categories is conservative if and only if every components of the counit is an extremal epimorphism"?

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti You can find it on page 44 of G.M. Kelly's "Basic concepts of enriched category theory", available online at http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10.pdf.

Comment: The lemma is also mentioned in this question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915675/g-conservative-iff-counit-components-are-extremal-epi?noredirect=1&lq=1